# How do I disable Entity Framework database initialization via app.config?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

(Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server)

I realize I can do it via code with

```cs
Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<FirmaContext>());
```

and that works, but I would like to configure it per-environment via app.config.

Below is what I currently have, but it's not preventing initialization (i.e. in `Database.Log`, I still see queries against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `dbo.__MigrationHistory`):

```xml
<entityFramework>
<!-- (defaultConnectionFactory and providers nodes ommitted) --> 
    <contexts>
      <context type="My.Long.Namespace.Data.DbContexts.MyContext, My.Long.Namespace.Data">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.NullDatabaseInitializer`1[[My.Long.Namespace.Data.DbContexts.MyContext, My.Long.Namespace.Data"/>
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

I also tried this to no avail:

```xml
<context type="My.Long.Namespace.Data.DbContexts.MyContext, My.Long.Namespace.Data" disableDatabaseInitialization="true">
</context>
```

(I got the assembly names via `(typeof(MyContext)).AssemblyQualifiedName` and `(typeof(NullDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>).AssemblyQualifiedName)`)

Comment: Why not in the `<appSettings>`?

Comment: As in check for a key and set the initializer through code? That's a good idea, thank you. I am still curious to know why my config entry doesn't work though.

Comment: Turns out using `appSettings` isn't ideal for me. I would prefer for the context and its project to be the one deciding, not all of the calling apps. I don't want other projects to worry about including an `appSettings` key